# How to add extra fields in CakeDc Users plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakedc

I am trying to add some extra fields in the `Cakedc Users` plugin default Users table

But I can't figure it out how to do it, I didn't find anything in the documentation about this problem, I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848943/cakedc-users-plugin-how-to-add-details-fieldi-e-first-name-company-in-to) here

But that person asked for a lot so he didn't get a lot of help, I also tried adding the extra field in the Mysql `users` table and in the `register.ctp` template  , But I find it's value is empty

Comment: What version of cakephp are you using?

Comment: This most likely has to do with the new field not being accessible for assignment in the entity class. The issue seems to something that has already be reported as a feature request: https://github.com/CakeDC/users/issues/276

Comment: @chrisShick Can you think of any hack so I can update this field only once when the user register ? I really need it

Comment: You can try my plugin as well that doesn't rely on a given table but can be mapped to any tables field names. https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-user-tools See the field mapping in the behavior. If you think I can improve something just let me know.

Comment: I would definitely recommend using @burzum plugin!!

Comment: @burzum thanks, But It would be diffuclt for me, Since  I already finished my project, And I am on a tight schedule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the question you mention is related to the previous version of the Plugin (for CakePHP 2).

You are doing right now, but the problem is the User Entity being too strict and blocking mass-assignment https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/3.1.5/src/Model/Entity/User.php#L30 (which is possibly a good thing to change in the Plugin itself to allow an even easier override). I'll add a ticket for this in a bit :)

In the current version it's very easy to extend the users table and add your own columns.
For example, let's say you want to add a new column to your users table "phone".

- Add a new column in users table (usually involving a migration, you can "bake" this migration using

> bin/cake bake migration AddPhoneToUsers phone:index

- Run the migration to apply the changes

> bin/cake bake migration migrate

- Now follow instructions here https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Extending-the-Plugin.md#extending-the-model-tableentity to:
- Create empty Model and Entity classes extending the plugin classes
- Override $accessible property in your new Entity to something like

  protected $_accessible = [
      '*' => true,
      'id' => false,
      'role' => false,
  ];
- Lastly, add this override to your bootstrap.php file after loading the Plugin

  Configure::write('Users.table', 'MyUsers');

The plugin will pick your customized Table and use the new fields coming from your custom register.ctp page.

We've created an improvement ticket here > https://github.com/CakeDC/users/issues/311 to relax $_accessible fields.

Thank you,

Comment: Can't believe this doesn't even have an upvote, +1. Btw, I'm using an approach of a secondary table for 'profile information' with an FK to users to kind of avoid conflicts incase any future fields come up. Are there any upcoming changes to CakeDC that might introduce new fields, and/or related to the new Authentication/Authorization plugins?

Comment: Yes we are working on a complete refactor to use authenticate. New fields are too tight to the app, but your approach works too, having a profile table to manage extra fields and using users for auth. Thanks,

Comment: Oh really. Any sort of guess on when it would be ready or for an rc/beta? I'd love to integrate this with the new authenticate to make my solution more forward-compatible.

Comment: Additionally, how backwards-compatible will the new cakedc users be?